# Ubuntu 16.04 SSD+HDD partitioning scheme

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd

So, with Ubuntu 16.04 coming I want to reinstall Ubuntu only on my 128GB SSD and 500GB HDD. I've looked around the web and I couldn't find any clear, beginner friendly information on how I should go about partitioning the drives to accomplish this:

- I want to use my SSD for the system and files that I have to access quickly
- I do gaming(which has improved a lot, especially CS:GO)
- I want to leave space for other linux distros, but no Windows
- I want big files on the HDD

What's the deal with /home, what are the advantages of having that on the HDD or the SSD, what directories should be on the SSD and which ones on the HDD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's imagine that SSD is the first priority boot device and named as /dev/**sda** and hard drive is the second and named as /dev/**sdb**. And I'm sure you are using [GPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) instead of old MBR.

You should definetely install your system to SSD, 30 gigabytes is quiet enough, but let's take 40. So the sda1 is your **/** (root) partition. Leave other 20 gigabytes for future installation. (If you would like to install more than 3 distros - then locate other's on hard drive). You have left 60 GB of free space on SSD for your games. Create ext4 pertition and name mounting point as `/home/user/.steam` (where instead `user` place your desired username) That will locate your steam library on SSD.

I recommend you creating partition on hard drive that is equal to your RAM size + 500 MB for swap and hibernation. The other space on hard drive use for your /home.

Finally **sda** (SSD):

- 40 GB partition for Ubuntu
- 20 GB of free space
- 60 GB for Steam library

**sdb** (Hard Drive):

- Swap partition
- Home

If the space on your steam library partition will end, you may add in Steam settings more library paths (Steam - Settings - Downloads- Library Paths)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry,  I voted to close because this is very opinion based.

My opinion is this -

Create 4 primary partitions on the SSD - 3 small ones of say 16 gigs each for your OS's, and use the remaining space for LVM.

Use LVM2 and create an SSD volume and Hard drive volume.  Create your root directory on 1 of the small partitions on the hard drive and use some of the space on the LVM partition for swap.   Leave free space on the LVM partition for other things you may want to add later.

Create a /data partition on the HDD LVM (again, leave space for later) - you can store your large files here.  You can also use symlinks or bound mounts to "graft" this space into your directory tree if parts of it need to appear in other places in your file system.